# duplicate row.names (index) error in zoo

Tags: r, zoo

I have encountered a duplicate index warning/error in zoo. I spent some time to troubleshoot, and it came down to the following data/snippet:

```
Lines = "Index,dbt,rh,dpt,wind.mph,gust.mph,wind.dir,voltage,klux,fc
2008-03-09 01:00:00,37.96,77.25,31.60,4.16,5.39,247,0.00,28.283,2643.28
2008-03-09 02:00:00,37.20,77.25,30.90,0.00,0.43,244,0.00,28.283,2643.28"

x <- read.table(header=T,text=Lines,sep=",")

library(zoo)

z = zoo(x[,2:10],as.POSIXct(x$Index))
```

If I run the above, I got the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In zoo(x[, 2:10], as.POSIXct(x$Index)) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

I was wondering what is wrong with the data/index. They are in fact different.

However, the following command:

```
library(xts)
make.index.unique(index(z))
```

gave a puzzling result:

```
[1] "2008-03-09 01:00:00 MST" "2008-03-09 01:00:00 MST"
```

Did the above command just make the indeces duplicates? Can anybody enlighten me on how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not so much with `zoo` as it is with the arguments to `as.POSIXct`

Have a look at `as.POSIXct(x$Index)` and you will see that it is not giving the results you require.

Giving `as.POSIXct` a time zone will help.

Compare:

```
as.POSIXct(x$Index)
#  [1] "2008-03-09 01:00:00 EST" "2008-03-09 01:00:00 EST"

as.POSIXct(x$Index, tz = "GMT")
#   [1] "2008-03-09 01:00:00 GMT" "2008-03-09 02:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: Also, try `read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", tz = "GMT")` or use chron which does not support time zones so you can't have these problems: `library(chron); read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", FUN = as.chron)` .